# How to check the current publisher type in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, combine, publisher

After putting some operators on a publisher I am curious as to what the current return value and/or error is. Is there a quick way in Xcode that you can check that?

I would like to see something like `Map<CombineLatest<Published<String>, Published<String>, String?>>`.

I know I don't need to know if I erase it with `.eraseToAnyPublisher`, but I like to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to insert the line

```
.map{$0}
```

– which practically does nothing – and <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `$0`

Comment: Yup that works =)